# .htaccess non-www to www causing 404 link error

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I changed my website from example.com to www.example.com in the .htaccess using this 301 redirect code below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The homepage works fine now and redirects properly to the www version instead of the non www version of my site which is what I wanted. But now the links on my site do not work at all and I'm getting a 404 doesn't exist page. I'm using Wordpress. How can I fix this?

Edit: Never mind, I fixed it. I realized I accidentally deleted the part that was needed for WordPress to work properly and put in the www code in its place. Thank you.

Comment: Post all your htaccess code in the question. Don't just post what you think might be causing the issue since you don't know what the problem is. Then someone can better assist. Also is this a WP 404 error or apache?

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it. I realized I accidentally deleted the part that was needed for WordPress to work properly and put in the www code in its place. Thank you.